# Should inheritable CSS properties accept the value “initial”?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Chrome and Safari, if we specify `initial` for an inheritable CSS property, it will select the `initial` value.

But if we specify `initial` for an inheritable CSS property in FireFox, IE, or Opera, it will reject that value assignment altogether.

Which is the *correct* behavior here?

[Test script](http://qweop.com/test/initial.php):

```
<!doctype html> 
<div style="color:red;">1111
    <div id="d2" style="color:blue;color:initial;">2222</div> 
</div> 
<script> 
document.write(document.getElementById("d2").style.color);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `initial` value seems to be [valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#initial0).

As CSS3 is (relatively) new and still prone to change, I suspect that not all browsers are up-to-date with the standardisation.

As stated by [Paul D. Waite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20578/paul-d-waite): it is part of the standard to have multiple definitions of the same property, of which the last one shoud win. So according to the standards your example, the color property of `#d2` should have the initial value, which is red. Browsers which show the blue color do not support the standard completely/properly.

Comment: “I do not know whether it is part of the standard to allow multiple definitions of the same property and how to cope with it.” — It is. Within a block, the last one wins. (I think that’s what the spec implies anyway, and it seems to be what browsers do.)

Comment: So for the code above, `div#d2` should, in browsers that don’t support `initial`, end up blue.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: Correct. Also if there are any `!important` declarations within the same block, the last `!important` one wins (except in IE6).

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: thanks for your addition, I updated my answer for completeness.